# Powershell Byte array to INT

Tags: arrays, powershell, byte, type-conversion

I have a byte array with two values: `07` and `DE` (in hex).

What I need to do is somehow concatenate the `07DE` and get the decimal value from that hex value. In this case, it is `2014`.

My code:

```
# This line gives 11 bytes worth of information
[Byte[]] $hexbyte2 = $obj.OIDValueB

# All I need are the first two bytes (the values in this case are 07 and DE in HEX)
[Byte[]] $year = $hexbyte2[0], $hexbyte2[1]
```

How do I combined these to make `07DE` and convert that to an int to get `2014`?

Comment: Which snmp oid is this?   hrPrinterDetectedErrorState?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use the .NET System.BitConvert class:

```
C:\PS> $bytes = [byte[]](0xDE,0x07)
C:\PS> [bitconverter]::ToInt16($bytes,0)
2014
```

Comment: You put it in backwards?

Comment: @js2010, his system probably `[System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian`; see [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int)

Comment: Oh I see.  The snmp bitstring is big endian, but reg_binary is little endian.

Comment: @Gregory I believe his bytes arrived the other way, big endian.  That seems to happen in snmp.

Comment: @js2010, meh as long as he knows `[0]` is `07` and `[1]` is `DE`, then the endianess would be determined by BitConverter and `$Endian=if([System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian){1,0}else{0,1};$bytes=[byte[]]($hexbyte2[$Endian]);`

Comment: in fact `$hexbyte2` is already a byte array so... `$Endian=if([System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian){1,0}else{0,1};[System.BitConverter]::ToInt16($hexbyte2[$Endian],0);`

Answer (score 2):

Accounting for Endianness while using the .NET System.BitConverter calss:

```
# This line gives 11 bytes worth of information
[Byte[]] $hexbyte2 = $obj.OIDValueB

# From the OP I'm assuming:
#   $hexbyte2[0] = 0x07
#   $hexbyte2[1] = 0xDE

$Endianness = if([System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian){1,0}else{0,1}
$year = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt16($hexbyte2[$Endianness],0)
```

Note, older versions of PowerShell would need to rework the `if` statement:

```
if([System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian){
   $Endianness = 1,0
}else{
   $Endianness = 0,1
}
```

see also [MSDN: How to convert a byte array to an int (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that should work. First you convert the bytes into hex, then you can concatenate that and convert to an integer.

```
[byte[]]$hexbyte2 = 0x07,0xde
$hex = -Join (("{0:X}" -f $hexbyte2[0]),("{0:X}" -f $hexbyte2[1]))
([convert]::ToInt64($hex,16))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just concatenate 2 integral values like that, you need to do a proper radix conversion. For example:

```
0x7DE = 7*256 + DE
```

Also note, that the result won;t fit in a byte, you need to store it in an int. So your example becomes:

```
[int]$year = $hexbyte[0]*([Byte]::MaxValue+1) + $hexbyte[1]
```