# Reversing byte order in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, endianness

I want to reverse the order of bytes in this Array

```
$cfg = ($cfg | ForEach-Object ToString X2)
```

I have tried

```
$cfg = [Array]::Reverse($cfg)
```

But after

```
Write-Output $cfg
```

There was no generated output. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: What does your variable `$cfg` hold?

Comment: `$cfg[($cfg.Count-1)..0]`  is another alternative

Comment: It might help if you were to explain the problem that you are really trying to solve (this seems like a possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Note: The answer below addresses reversing a given array's elements, *whatever their type may be*. The command in your question creates an array of *strings*, not *bytes*. If you wanted to interpret these strings as *byte values*, you'd have to use: `[byte[]] $cfg = ($cfg | ForEach-Object ToString X2) -replace '^', '0x'`

That said, given that your command implies that the elements of `$cfg` are *numbers* already,

`[byte[]] $cfg = $cfg` should do.</sup>

[`[Array]::Reverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.Reverse) reverses an array *in place* and has *no return value*.

Therefore, use just `[Array]::Reverse($cfg)` *by itself* - after that, `$cfg`, will contain the original array elements in reverse order.

A simple example:

```
$a = 1, 2, 3

# Reverse the array in place.
[Array]::Reverse($a)

# Output the reversed array -> 3, 2, 1
$a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convert a byte array to integer in LittleEndian order or "backwards"... (based on [Powershell Byte array to INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457902/powershell-byte-array-to-int/24463023#24463023))

```
[bitconverter]::ToInt16   # without parentheses to get declaration

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static int16 ToInt16(byte[] value, int startIndex)


$bytes = [byte[]](0xde,0x07)
$startIndex = 0

[bitconverter]::ToInt16($bytes,$startIndex)
2014

2014 | % tostring x4
07de                     # bytes are backwards

[bitconverter]::IsLittleEndian   # Windows, OSX, Linux...
True
```